# Scale Mouse position for different monitor

Tags: c#

i want to generate mouse click on a button (mouse hooking). i found this button at (420,50) position in 1280 X 800 monitor and (480,50) position in 1440 X 900 size monitor. Is there any algorithm or c# api to scale mouse position on different monitors.

Comment: Can you clarify how this button position is scaled? 1280/1440 is not 420/480 and 800/900 is obviously not 50/50. If it scaled with resolution you should have: 1280x800 -> (420,50); 1440x900 -> (472.5, 56.25)

Comment: may i know how you have calculated 1440x900 -> (472.5, 56.25) ?  . i have a button in (X,Y) in 1280 X 800 monitor. may i know where will be the button (X1,Y1 ?) in the monitor 1440 X 900. (Note : it is scaled with resolution)

Comment: 1440/1280 * 420 = 472.5; 900/800 * 50 = 56.25; in other words: `newPositionX = newWidth / oldWidth * oldPositionX`; analogous for y

Answer (score 0):

Depending on if this is a website or an application then you may have to just create a list for different monitor sizes. This is because in the case of a website the position of the button may not scale directly with the size of the screen. In the case that you know for a fact it does, then just find the percentage coordinates, e.i. 480 is what % of 1280, and 50 is what % of 800. The you simply find the screen size and multiply it by the x or y percentage. But from the coordinates you provided it doesn't look like the y component moves so you may only need to find the x component.